# How to transform this limit $\lim_{h \to 0}\left(1+h\right)^{\frac{x}{h}}=e^x$ into $\lim_{h \to 0}\left(1+xh\right)^{\frac{1}{h}}=e^x$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, limsup-and-liminf

How to transform this limit $\lim_{h \to 0}\left(1+h\right)^{\frac{x}{h}}=e^x$ into $\lim_{h \to 0}\left(1+xh\right)^{\frac{1}{h}}=e^x$?

This seems like I can't simplify this limit because I end up with zero divisors.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set $t=xh \Rightarrow \frac{1}{h} = \frac{x}{t}$.

Hence,
$$\lim_{h\to 0} (1+xh)^{\frac{1}{h}}= \lim_{t\to 0}\left((1+t)^{\frac{1}{t}}\right)^x = e^x$$

**Additional info after comment:**

The other way round works a bit differently.

You start with $(1+h)^{\frac{1}{h}}$.

Now, you need to squeeze in the $x$. Naturally, in this case, you have $h=x\frac{h}{x}$. So, $t = \frac{h}{x}$.

This would finally lead to $\lim_{t\to 0}\left((1+xt)^{\frac{1}{t}}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}} = e$.

Raising this to the power of $x$ gives $\lim_{t\to 0}(1+xt)^{\frac{1}{t}} = e^x$

Comment: Is there a reason why I can't solve when having $y = \frac{x}{h}$ and developing? Why must I choose $t = xh$?

Comment: @galosec Why would you want to use $x/h$? You'd then be trying to evaluate $\lim_{y\to\infty}(1+x^2/y)^{y/x}$.

Comment: @gatosec : You want to reproduce the expression $(1+y)^{\frac{1}{y}}$ where $y \to 0$. In the case $y=\frac{x}{h}$, your $y$ does not tend to 0 anymore when $h$ tends to 0.

Comment: @trancelocation, there is a slight problem here. If we define $t = xh$ so when $h \to 0$ then $t \to 0$, and if we try to develop from the **first expression**, we get: $\lim_{t \to 0}(1 + \frac{t}{x})^{\frac{x}{t}} = e$, and it seems nonsensical.

Comment: @gatosec : I have added some info to my answer addressing the other way round you would like to have.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\lim_{h\to0}(1+h)^{\frac1h}=e$, you have$$\lim_{h\to0}(1+xh)^{\frac1{xh}}=e$$too and therefore\begin{align}\lim_{h\to0}(1+xh)^{\frac1h}&=\lim_{h\to0}\left((1+xh)^{\frac1{xh}}\right)^x\\&=\left(\lim_{h\to0}(1+xh)^{\frac1{xh}}\right)^x\\&=e^x.\end{align}

Comment: You forgot the $=$ sign: $\lim_{h\to0}(1+h)^{\frac1h}=e$

Comment: I've edited my answer. Thank you.